# How to clone files in edit mode through P4 plugin on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, perforce, jenkins-groovy

P4 plugin (https://plugins.jenkins.io/p4/) on Jenkins through jenkins pipeline script - how to check out files in edit mode? tried allwrite option as true.

Tried below script for checkout.

```
p4sync charset: 'utf8', credential: 'abc', populate: syncOnly(force: true, have: true, modtime: false, parallel: [enable: false, minbytes: '1024', minfiles: '1', threads: '4'], pin: '', quiet: true, revert: false),workspace: manualSpec(charset: 'utf8', cleanup: false, name: '<workspace_name>', pinHost: false, spec: clientSpec(streamName: '<stream_name>', allwrite: true, backup: true, clobber: true, compress: false, line: 'LOCAL', locked: false, modtime: false, rmdir: false, serverID: '', type: 'WRITABLE'))
```

Still files are checked out in readonly mode and not able to edit/modify/update through script.

Comment: I'm not sure how to express this in the Jenkins language, but in Perforce you `p4 edit` a read-only file to open it for edit (which makes it locally writable).  Can you do a `p4edit` on the files after your `p4sync`?

Comment: are you saying the OS file is not writable?   
It should be from your p4sync task syntax. 
The p4 client workspace has "allwrite: true" and your populate syncOnly has force:true which is a "p4 sync -f".

Comment: If allwrite: false then after the sync do Sam's suggestion -  use p4groovy to "p4 edit" the file(s), such as "p4.run("edit","//path/to/file")" which will make it OS writable.